# XGrabPointer poll till next event or pipe

Tags: pthreads, x11

I was trying to write a mouse event listener. This was my approach, can you please tell me if this will work before I start writing it. I'm writing it in ctypes, so if I ctype it all (couple days) then find out it doesnt work its a loss of time.

My goal is, that I should be able to cancel the poll via a pipe. This was my approach:

1. In another thread call `XThreadsInit`
2. Open XDisplay `display`
3. `XGrabPointer` to `display`
4. get file descriptor `ConnectionNumber(display)`
5. connect to pipe that was made on main thread
6. Do a `pselect` with no timeout `timeout` is set to `null` on pipe and fd from 4

Is this right approach?
Thanks

Comment: `XGrabPointer` prevents other clients from using the mouse.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. so my algo above is not accurate for a sync/blocking method that polls until disrupted either by next monitored event or pipe?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using threads you are sharing variables between threads. It would be much simpler to use a global variable that is set when the poll must be aborted, then in your watch thread create a tight loop that checks for that variable and use a short timeout in pselect(). This may introduce a short delay but if you keep the timeout short (say, 100 ms) it would be hardly noticable and still efficient.

Comment: Thanks JvO excuse my missing this comment :) I really need to avoid the short delay :( Need it it indefinite and only interruptable by a pipe someone recommended `pthreads`

Comment: Well, using threads is one way... if all you need to do is send a byte to a socket so that your poll() returns, it doesn't matter where that byte is coming from. Could be a thread, a child process that is forked() or even an external program that uses a network socket or a Unix pipe. The problem with threads is that they're difficult to avoid race conditions. But if no delay is desired, then by all means try it.